# How to generate sql script for Spring's embedded database?

Tags: spring, unit-testing, initialization, embedded-database, spring-jdbc

I'm using Spring embedded database in my unit tests. From Spring documentantatio:

```
<jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource">
    <jdbc:script location="classpath:schema.sql"/>
    <jdbc:script location="classpath:test-data.sql"/>
</jdbc:embedded-database>
```

There are many examples all over the web which basically tell the same tale. I am able to manually create the sql statements from the production database. I could use mysqldump for example (assuming the SQL produced is accepted by HSQL). But my tables are already defined in .hbm.xml files. Is there a way to generate them automatically into the .sql files?

The purpose of all this is naturally to initialize the database. My immediate intent is to only setup the tables; I'll insert the necessary test data in the unit tests themselves.

Comment: You may modify code from my answer about JPA: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856934/how-to-generate-schema-for-jpa-entity/6883384#6883384

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could let Hibernate generate your schema from the mapping file(s). You wouldn't then need to have a script do it for your integration tests. Check out the [Hibernate Toolset Guide](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/toolsetguide.html) for how to do this.

Alternatively you could Retag this question for the database you are working with and see the best way of creating a schema generation script.

Comment: I believe I should go with hibernate as far as I can. I don't want to create unnecessary dependencies with any certain database. How would I create the schema with hibernate?

Comment: Check out the Hibernate Toolset Guide - http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/toolsetguide.html.